# Converting a subroutine into a function

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following subroutine that takes a predefined list of strings (call this my big list) in column A and depending on if a string in another column is a sub string of one of the strings in my big list, it replaces it. If there is no match, it doesn't do anything (just leaves the string as is).

```
Sub Find_Bad_Replace_Good()
    Dim rng As Range, v As Long, vList As Variant
    With Selection.Parent
        vList = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value2
        For Each rng In Selection
            For v = LBound(vList, 1) To UBound(vList, 1)
                If CBool(InStr(1, rng.Value2, vList(v, 1), vbTextCompare)) Then
                    rng = vList(v, 1)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next v
        Next rng
    End With
End Sub
```

I want to covert it to a function that accepts a string as an argument (coming from a single cell) instead of a macro that works on the entire range of strings. I'm hoping one of you experts can help me. I want this so I can have more control and the macro seems to freeze.

Comment: A function cannot change any cell other than the cell is is in. You can write it as a sub that accepts a parameter.

Comment: Hello Jeeped. Thanks for your quick reply. I only want it to change the value of the cell it's in, and I want to use the function to autofill on that range. I just need the value in the cell it's in to change depending on if it's a substring of one of the words in my big list which is in Column A

Comment: But if the function is in a cell, you would have to reference another cell for the value or hard-code it into the function call. It could then return the alternate value to the cell that it is in.

Comment: Ah okay. I'm unsure how I could resolve this then, the subroutine as is is much to slow and causes my workbook to freeze. If there was a way to reference the A column in the function parameter so I have 2 parameters that would work as well.

Comment: Possibly a named range (Formulas ► Name Manager) with workbook scope would reference the 'big list' more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked the rest of your code, since I don't have Excel here. But this is the general syntax to convert to a function:

```
Function Find_Bad_Replace_Good(inputValue as String) As String

    Dim v As Long, vList As Variant
    With ActiveSheet
        vList = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value2
        For v = LBound(vList, 1) To UBound(vList, 1)
            If CBool(InStr(1, inputValue, vList(v, 1), vbTextCompare)) Then
                Find_Bad_Replace_Good = vList(v, 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next v
    End With

End Function
```

See that where you used to access `rng.Value2` I've switched to `inputValue`, which will be the string passed as argument to the function. The return is also a string, and takes the same name as the function. So where you used to assign the result of your search to `rng`, now I'm assigning to `Find_Bad_Replace_Good`, which will be the return value for you function.

I also changed your `with` to `With ActiveSheet`, since you don't have a selection anymore. Just change it to be the range you want.

Comment: Your `.Range` or `.Cells`don't appear to have a parent.

Comment: Nice. Will the vList hard code the 'big list' into the function as Jeeped mentioned?

Comment: you are right, @Jeeped. @mrL, yes you can hard code the range in vList, or you can pass another argument to the function, a range, and use it instead. Like `Function Find_Bad_Replace_Good(inputValue as String, vList as Range) `

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes that you have given your 'big list' a name with workbook scope. This action can be as easy as typing a valid name into the Name Box to the left of the address bar while the range of cells is selected. For the sake of backwards conformity, I'll use the name **vList**.

```
Function udf_Alternate_Word(str As String)
    udf_Alternate_Word = "no match"
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(Chr(42) & str & Chr(42), Range("vList"), 0)) Then _
        udf_Alternate_Word = Range("vList").Cells(Application.Match(Chr(42) & str & Chr(42), Range("vList"), 0), 1).Value2
End Function
```