# How to display a changing message box on error and then continue code

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I have a macro that runs multiple other macros. I would like for the code to skip to the next macro if there is an error with one of the macros it calls. I would also like that a message box appears when an error occurs so that I know in which macro the error occured. So, I would like that the message box that appears if an error occurs changes so that it tells me the name of that macro.

```
Sub Update_ALL()

                ' Run All the macros

                    Call Macro_1

                    Call Macro_2

                    Call Macro_3

                    Call Macro_4  

                    Call Macro_5  

                    Call Macro_6 

                    Call Macro_7 

                    Call Macro_8                    

End Sub
```

The code is very simple but I can't figure out how to skip to the next macro on error and have a changing message box.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: make each macro a function that returns a value instead of a subroutine, and then check the value each returns after it is run to see if you want to continue.

Comment: would the code stop after each macro? The reason why I call the macros in one code is that the macros are very long to run, so I want the next macro to automatically start when one finishes

Comment: Also, I do not know of the make a macro into a function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621065/converting-a-subroutine-into-a-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your "macros" to handle and re-throw errors, specifying an argument for the error's `Source` in the call to `Err.Raise`:

```
Public Sub Macro_1()
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    '...original code here...
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    Err.Raise Err.Number, "Macro_1", Err.Description
End Sub
```

If an error occurs while executing `Macro_1`, the `Err.Source` will be "Macro_1".

Now in the "main" procedure, you need to handle these errors bubbling up - pop a `MsgBox` and use `Err.Source` as e.g. the title (or as you please), and then `Resume Next` to clear the error state and move on to the next macro:

```
Public Sub Update_All()
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    Macro_1
    Macro_2
    '...
    Macro_8
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Source
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Consider renaming your procedures using meaningful names, e.g. `FormatSummarySheet`, or `UpdateOrdersTable`.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this!